# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition take around 30 - 40 sec to get the position in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code, but to fetch the coordinates (lat,long) takes me 30 - 40 sec to get the position.

Please help me in getting quick response from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` within 2-3 secs

Below is my code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position){
    $scope.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    $scope.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+$scope.latitude+','+$scope.longitude+'&key=', function(data){
        //here web service call to fetch job list based on location
    });
},
function (error){
    //here web service call to fetch job list without location
},
{
    maximumAge:150000, 
});
```

I have also tried passing extra options like `timeout :5000`, but it comes to error code and gives me full list which should not happen if user allows location.

I want my job list to be loaded based on user allowing location, so only after user choosing option from popup I want to display joblist, so I have to get the user location position immediately to get job list immediately. Please help me out here.

Comment: Did you try `enableHighAccuracy: false` for the [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions/enableHighAccuracy)? It's `false` by default (According to the specs) but the following configuration work for me: `{ enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 0 }`

Comment: yes I have tried with that option as well. thing is the above options you have mentioned  it gets timeout after 5sec and goes to error part of it which gives response from the error code part , but i want  list based on user location. this happens for the first load later I get it withini 2-3sec (incase if i mention maximumAge:150000)